# Lenovo ServeRAID M5210 controller in non Lenovo/IBM Servers

Tags: raid, ibm, lenovo

I hope you can help me. I purchased this controller "ServeRAID M5210"

https://lenovopress.lenovo.com/tips1069-serveraid-m5210-sas-sata-controller

I am trying to use it in a custom build home lab server. However I do not get it working. I see the controller being recognized during boot, but I am not able to access the controller bios. Also in the OS it is shown as faulty. I tried Windows, Linux and ESXi. No luck.

Is it possible that this controller only works with Lenovo / IBM servers?

Many thanks for your help.

BR
Markus

Answer (score 0):

It's an ordinary LSI-based controller, it may require a custom tool (like Dell-badged LSI-based controllers) but it should work in any server. Maybe it's really faulty? In Linux does it appear in `lspci`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the controller is only supported on a *subset* of Lenovo / IBM servers: https://lenovopress.lenovo.com/tips1069-serveraid-m5210-sas-sata-controller#server-support; not even *all* servers from the same vendor are supported.

So, yes, it's completely possible for it to just *not work* outside its support boundaries.